# How to get the id from another post form when using a multiple image uploader using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two forms the blog post and multiple image uploader, basically I want to use multiple image uploader in the blog post form, however I need to get the ID from blog post form so each blog posts has it's own unique set of images. I am aware you can use foreign keys to establish the link between the two tables but I am unsure how to do this. Right now the blog post form only does a single file upload so I want a way to use the multiple image uploader logic into the PostController which then saves into the images table. Really appreciate the help thank you.

ImagesController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(!$this->validate($request, [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'images.*' => 'sometimes|image|nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,webp|max:25000',
            'post_id' => 'required'
        ])) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('errors');
        }

        if($request->hasfile('images'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();

                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

                $path = $image->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

                $image = new Images;
                $image->images = $fileNameToStore;
                $image->post_id = $request->post_id;
                $image->save();
            }
        }

        return back()->with('Images have been uploaded!');
    }
```

PostController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate posted form data
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'id' => 'integer',
            'vehicle'    => 'required|string',
            'h1' => 'required|string',
            'page_title' => 'required|string',
            'meta_description' => 'required|string',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|nullable|max:5000',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'active' => 'integer',
            'user_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Create slug from title
        $validated['slug'] = Str::slug($validated['vehicle'], '-');

        $validated['active'] = isset($request->active[0]) ? 1 : 0;

            if($request->hasFile('image'))
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

                $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

                $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

                $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);
            }else {
                $fileNameToStore = null;
            }

        // Create and save post with validated data
        $post = new Post;
        $post->id = $request->input('id');
        $post->vehicle = $request->input('vehicle');
        $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $post->h1 = $request->input('h1');
        $post->page_title = $request->input('page_title');
        $post->meta_description = $request->input('meta_description');
        $post->image = $fileNameToStore;
        $post->content = $request->input('content');
        $post->active = $validated['active'];
        $post->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $post->slug =  $validated['slug'];
        $post->save();

        // Redirect the user to the created post with a success notification
        return redirect(route('admin.posts.show', $post))->with('notification', 'Post created!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store images in your `PostController`.

Remove this part in your `PostController` (in `store()` method):

```
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);
        }else {
            $fileNameToStore = null;
        }
```

And after creating the `post` put the loop to save images. Change this line:

```
$image->post_id = $request->post_id;
```

to this:

```
$image->post_id = $post->id;
```

First use the `Images` model at the top of the `PostController`. Your new loop should looks like this:

```
    if($request->hasfile('images'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
        {
            $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();

            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            $path = $image->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

            $image = new Images;
            $image->images = $fileNameToStore;
            $image->post_id = $post->id;
            $image->save();
        }
    }
```

Then (based on relationships in your models) you can access the image with something like this:

```
@foreach($post->images as $image)
    <img src="public/image{{ $image->fileNameToStore">
@endforeach
```

Comment: But wouldn't  $post->id be an undefined variable? I have a made those changes so would I then copy the form from the images view into the blog posts view?

Comment: You have saved the post, so the `$post->id` has a value and surely it's not undefined. And yes, you can move the images section to the post form.

Comment: The problem I'm getting now is the post_id is null so it's not retrieving the ID

Comment: Can you return `$post->id` after saving the post?

Comment: Got it working it's returning the correct ID, it was a caching problem. So images and id are storing the database. I get this error for the images You don't have permission to access /storage/image/ on this server. I'm using storage link to store the images.

Comment: Also how would display the images onto the view would I use $images->images or $post->images?

Comment: First, you have to check permissions and paths.

Comment: So the problem is in the view it doesn't seem to be returning file name of the image.


`<img class="mb-2 edit-post-image" width="100%" src="{{ Storage::url("image/{$image->images}") }}"/>`